# application initializing document picker is missing the icloud entitlement

Tags: iphone, react-native, icloud

I am using 'react-native-document-picker' library and using iphone 6 simulator.
I am getting an exception: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement', whenever I clicked on the button. how can I resolve this issue? 
please suggest me any solution. thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';
export class EditInformation extends Component {

 docPicker() {
  DocumentPicker.show({
  filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()]
   },(error, res) => {
 });
}
render() {
 return (
   <View>
     <Button onPress={() => this.docPicker()}>
        <Text> Upload image </Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have apple paid developer account and setup your own iCloud account with capabilities settings of Xcode.

Comment: I have iCloud account, but still i am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

at the top of the .m file